# Salesforce CRM Content library

Tags: content

I am adding to a library as workspace administrator.

I am still not able to see edit button to the file i uploaded in the library.

i am also added as viewer to same library via public group **"All internal users"**

Is that creating issue?

When admin logs in as my user and goes to the library he is able to see edit button under my name.

why i am not seeing edit button to file i uploaded in the library even when i am added as workspace administrator (and as viewer via a publc group)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Set Up --> Content Permissions --> Edit Library Administrator, and give yourself all the permissions you need.